# Unable to trigger DataTrigger on Menuitem.icon image binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, datatrigger

I'm trying to create a generic template where i can use binding parent property to set couple of properties.

here is the code:

```html
<MenuItem Header="Item 1 "
          IsEnabled="false">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="{StaticResource MyImage}" Width="20" >
                                <Image.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Image">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=MenuItem, AncestorLevel=2}, Path=IsEnabled}"  Value="false">
                                                <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource GrayScaleEffect}"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=MenuItem, AncestorLevel=2}, Path=IsEnabled}"  Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Image.Style>
                            </Image>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
          </MenuItem>
```

problem i'm facing is below code is not being triggered when the IsEnable Property of MenuItem is set to false.

```html
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=MenuItem, AncestorLevel=2}, Path=IsEnabled}"  Value="false">
                                                <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource GrayScaleEffect}"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
```

I've also tried TemplatedParent, TemplateBinding but none has worked. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You need to override the default template of the MenuItem. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Shortest solution i could think of is use property from VM

<MenuItem Header="Grayout effect" IsEnabled="False" >
 <MenuItem.Icon>
  <Image Source="{StaticResource MyImage}" Width="20"  >
   <Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Image">
     <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding boolShowGrayedImage}" Value="true">
       <Setter Property="Image.Effect" Value="{StaticResource GrayscaleEffect}"/>
      </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
   </Image.Style>
  </Image>
 </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>

Comment: Does it work? As an alternative, you may drop Menu but use Listbox or ListView and host it in a Popup.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is wrong `AncestorLevel` value, you should change it to `1`. The AncestorLevel parameter is optional parameter, you can remove it, if you haven't other `MenuItem` objects in higher level.

Comment: I have tested with `<Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.1"/>`. So maybe there is additional problem with `GrayScaleEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution that worked for me:

```
<Style x:Key="GrayScaleStyle" TargetType="Image">
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self }}" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="Image.Effect" Value="{StaticResource GrayscaleEffect}"/>
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.1"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

```
<MenuItem Header="Grayout effect" IsEnabled="False" >
<MenuItem.Icon>
    <Image Source="{StaticResource MyImage}" Width="20" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=., RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"  Style="{StaticResource GrayScaleStyle}"/>
</MenuItem.Icon>
```